# How can I anchor a view to the top when using ViewPropertyAnimator and scaleY?

Tags: android, animation, view

I'm trying to animate a view in Android (API 15) so it is shown by expanding down from the top and hidden by shrinking back up, exactly like [this jQuery slideUp()/slideDown() example](http://jsfiddle.net/mainwave/j28ygrc7/).

I've tried implementing this using [`ViewPropertyAnimator.scaleY(float)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#scaleY(float)) as follows:

**Hide:**

```
view.animate()
    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
    .scaleY(0f)
    .start();
```

**Show:**

```
view.animate()
    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
    .scaleY(1f)
    .start();
```

This works, except that the view shrinks to and expands from the vertical centre, rather than the top.

Is there a way to anchor this animation at the top, still using `ViewPropertyAnimator`? If not, what's the best alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

adjust the pivot as needed **before** the animation

```
view.setPivotY(0f); // 0 = top of the view
```

ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPivotY(float)